# Edit the make:entity command

Tags: doctrine-orm, console, symfony4

I would like to edit the `make:entity` command provided by the MakerBundle in Symfony 4.

Here is an explaination : the command adds the field `Id` by default in each entity. I would like automatically add other fields. That is why I want to edit the `make:entity` command.

I can also create a new Bundle that adds a new command like `my:make:entity`. But if I add a new command, I don't want that `make:entity` still usable anymore. I have an OpenSource project and I don't want somemone to use the old `make:entity` command. So, if I can't edit the `make:entity` command, can I deactivate it ?

Thank you in advance,

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork the github repository from :
https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle

and then make any modifications you like, commit and push to your fork. 
Then you need to tell composer to use your fork instead of the official repo by adding a "repositories" section to the end of your composer.json file

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/[your github]/maker-bundle"
    }
],
```

I hope this helps.